# How do I use an imported MNIST dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, import, keras, python-import, mnist

I'm not familiar with using python as a ML tool and wanted to train the MNIST data set. I have downloaded the MNIST library using
`pip install python-mnist` but do not know what my next step should be. What would an import statement look like? Should I also import TensorFlow and or Keras to train the data?

I know the MNIST dataset is available in TensorFlow and Keras, however,  importing via pip a necessary solution for my use case. Both TensorFlow and Keras have tutorials using the MNIST data set, but I was wondering if it is possible to use the data set without using their pre-downloaded library.

Comment: What's your objective? You can use R too if you're comfortable with it. Keras is relatively easy to understand. If you need it, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The import statement should look like this

```
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('./dir_with_mnist_data_files')
images, labels = mndata.load_training()
```

then you can work directly with the arrays of raw images and labels.